# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result')

Tags: list, flutter, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to generate a 300 list like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "Zulfa Application",
    home: new Home(data: new List<String>.generate(300,(i)=>"Ini data ke $i"),),
  ));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> data;
  Home({required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar : new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        title: new Text("Zulfalogy Content"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return new ListTile(
              leading: new Icon(Icons.widgets),
              title: new Text("${data[index]}"),
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And it thrown an error like this:
`_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' of 'function result')`

I didnt know how its going. i just following some tutorial and it still error. Hope u guys can help me to solve this:)

Comment: This widget does not show any errors as you described. Can you include your flutter version?

Comment: my flutter version is 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I have been copying your code as you post it and it worked fine for me
could you share your flutter version. or try to upgrade your flutter sdk.[image]

or try to copy this >>

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(new MaterialApp(
title: "Zulfa Application",
home:  Home(data:  List.generate(300,(i)=>"Ini data ke $i"),),
));
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

final List? data;
Home({ this.data});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
appBar : new AppBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
title: new Text("Zulfalogy Content"),
),
body: new Container(
child: new ListView.builder(
itemCount: data!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index){
return new ListTile(
leading: new Icon(Icons.widgets),
title: new Text("${data![index]}"),
);
}
),
),
);
}
}

Comment: my flutter version is 2.8.1

Comment: its working today when i rerun this code. thank you very much.